# -ErrorAction with Get-ADComputer not hiding errors

Tags: powershell

I'm just beginning to dip into PowerShell with AD so I apologize if the question seems obvious.

I am trying to check if which of the devices provided in a list are in AD. So far I've used the code from:
[Powershell - verify object exists in AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525313/powershell-verify-object-exists-in-ad)

It works just fine, but the "-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue" does not actually suppress the error messages. I get the below:

---

> Get-ADComputer : Cannot find an object with identity: 'test' under:
>   'DC=test,DC=dom'.
>   At C:\Users\testaccount\Desktop\test.ps1:171
>   char:19
>   +             if (@(Get-ADComputer $target -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Count)
>   +                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (test:ADComputer) [Get-ADComputer], ADIdentityNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer

---

The code I am using is as follows:

```
foreach ($target in $devicelist)
{
    if (@(Get-ADComputer $target -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Count)
    {
        $existingdevices += $target
    }
    else
    {
        #display error notification
    }
}
```

What I am looking for is suppressing the error message to no longer show in console - for the script to actually silently continue on error.

Any and all help will be appreciated!

Comment: use the `try/catch` version shown in that link with the `-ErrorAction` set to `Stop`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey
Thanks! That did help, but I was wondering why it wouldn't with the `if/else -erroraction` setup?

Comment: i don't know. [*blush*] i don't have access to the AD cmdlets ... but they are **_notorious_** for not doing what a proper PoSh cmdlet _should_ do. ///// besides,  the `try/catch` version is more standard, more controlled, AND easier to understand if one is familiar with the structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So lets talk about whats happening.

There are 2 types of errors **Terminating** and **Non-Terminating**.

Terminating stops the execution of a command and throws an Exception. A non-terminating returns a write-out error message.

`-ErrorAction` takes care of Non-Terminating errors

`Try{}Catch{}` takes care of Terminating errors.

In your case

```
foreach ($target in $devicelist)
{
    try{
        if (@(Get-ADComputer $target -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Count)
        {
            $existingdevices += $target
        }
        else
        {
            #display non-terminating error notification
        }
    }catch{
        #display Terminating error notification
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful explanation, now I get it.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: Also worth noting that `-ErrorAction Stop` basically turns non-terminating errors into terminating errors so you can catch them with `try { } catch { }`.

Answer (score 0):

Use output redirection: 2> $Null

Get-ADComputer -Server BlahBlah -Identity ComputerThatDoesntExist 2> $Null